# How can I open a pdf link when click a button on Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, nsurl

I am trying to open a pdf from my `Swift` application but I cannot make it to work.

I know that there are a lot of questions related with this and in most of them they use this code:

```
UIApplication.shared.openURL(URL(string: "http://www.url.com" + id)!)
```

But I am getting the following error:

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

so I thought that the error was because the `id` was nil so I made two `prints` to see what was retrieved: one for `url` and one for `id`. Both of them are correct and if I copy the url on the browser navigation bar it works perfectly (I cannot provide the real `url` because it is of a client).

I have this function wrapped inside an `@IBAction` to detect when a button is clicked so I looked if the connection had been broken. It is also correct.

So I cannot understand why this error is happening. I spent some hours but cannot figure out what is causing this error.

Am I missing something? Should I codify the url in some way?

**P.S:** I am using `Xcode8` and `Swift3`.

**UPDATE:** If I set `www.google.es` it is working perfectly. Can it be a problem using variables inside of the url?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Split up your code so you can see the cause. Build the string first. Then create the `URL`. Then call `openURL`. Then you'll find the real reason.

Comment: It is giving to me `nil` value when I use `URL(string: mystring)` but if I copy the url on the browser navigation bar it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, after some hours searching about the problem and following the recommendation of `@rmaddy` (Thanks!) I have split my function in three parts and I could see that the URL was returning `nil` value.

It was strange because I could copy the string into my browser navigation bar and it worked well so I thought that it could be something about encoding. One time I have encoded it I noticed that the `id` of the pdf was retrieved with a `\r` at the final of the `id`. Like this:

```
id004.pdf\r
```

The solution that I have done is the following:

```
var string = "http://www.url.com" + id
var index1 = string.index(string.endIndex, offsetBy: -1)
var substring1 = string.substring(to: index1)

let encodedString = substring1.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed)
UIApplication.shared.openURL(NSURL(string: encodedString!) as! URL)
```

Encoded string is necessary because if not the link no longer work.